# gnus do not display images

Tags: images

I subscribe  gwene.com.stackexchange.tex from gnus.

The images  includes in an article are displayed as a black rectangle. After a lot of time images can display as they should, but after emacs-restart the issue is back.

I try to open a downloaded png image with eww-open-file. Same result.
My Emacs-version is GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.0)

Starting `emacs -q` makes no difference nor does Emacs25.

It must exist something which trigger the correct display, but I did not find it. I need some help!

Comment: Very strange. If I visit https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466211/how-add-more-space-in-longtable  from gnus, the images are  displayed as black rectangle. If I compile the latex code producing the images, the display is just fine when I refresh

Comment: The issue is likely to come from the hardware. The mass memory of the machine is an eMMC that has a fairly short life and has already made jokes. I  changed the machine and the issue is fixed